# How to retain the entered data in the app using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an settings page in my app. The data entered are stored to the DB. when I close and open the settings page the fields are set to blank, and I don't want this to happen, instead hold the entered data in the settings even if the app is closed and re-opened. How to do this in the angularjs ?

Comment: Angular is a fully front-end client application. There is no way you can hold the entered data if you have closed the browser. Either you store it in your local storage / cache, or have to fetch it again from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage` or `cookies`

Comment: will localStorage hold the information even if app is closed and opened again??

Comment: Yes it will. That is what i use. But if you don't trust it just use cookies.

Comment: can you give me a example because I tried and it didn't end well